# Django 2.2.4 with DRF 3.9.4 - Not supporting GET method JSON body?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

this:

```
curl "http://localhost:8000/v1/post" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' \
     -d $'{
  "url": "/my-test-url"
}'
```

with this:

```
class PostView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data['url'])
        result = {}
        return Response(result)
```

crashes on the print line...

```
  KeyError: 'url'
```

**However**, changing the GET into a POST:

```
curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:8000/v1/post" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' \
     -d $'{
  "url": "/my-test-url"
}'

class PostView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data['url'])
        result = {}
        return Response(result)
```

will print it fine.

```
/my-test-url
[26/Nov/2019 22:00:42] "POST /v1/post HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

This causes me to believe either Django can't handle `GET` request body payload and that I must use URL parameters instead with `GET` --- or that I'm missing something.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET` requests have no body, that's why `data` is empty.

If you wanted to pass something using a `GET` request you would need to use querystring params (eg: `http://localhost:8000/v1/post?url=myurl`), then you can get them back using `request.query_params` rather than `request.data` (eg: `request.query_params['url']`).

Take a look to the [DRF Request Parsing](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#request-parsing) documentation for further details.

Comment: yeah. figured that much, but this is a Django decision, not HTTP. HTTP spec does not forbid using body on a GET.  Servers like ElasticSearch use a JSON body on GET extensively.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

`curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/v1/post -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -d '{"url": "/my-test-url"}'`